# Selecting folders with UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

I'm developing a new app and I would like the user to be able to select a folder from iCloud or an external drive. How can I allow them to select a folder using a UIDocumentBrowserViewController?

I have tried setting the allowedContentTypes to the UTI of folders, 'public.directory', but the document browser doesn't allow folders to be selected.

```swift
UIDocumentBrowserViewController(forOpeningFilesWithContentTypes: ["public.directory"])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an [official Apple solution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories) for iOS 13:

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeFolder as String], in: .open)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.directoryURL = startingDirectory
present(documentPicker, animated: true)
```

The constant `kUTTypeFolder` comes from `import CoreServices`.